# How to change file encode from perl script

Tags: perl, text, utf-8

I am writing below code into my script but it is not working. Our requirement is need to convert the file from UTF-8 to ANSI

```
iconv -c -f  UTF-8 -t MS-ANSI $file > $file2;
```

How to do this in in perl?

Comment: https://metacpan.org/search?q=iconv

Comment: $converter = Text::Iconv->new("UTF-8", "MS-ANSI");, this statement is  not working.. please suggest, already included library..

Comment: I can't reproduce any failure of that statement. Obviously, you have to write the rest of the script though.

Comment: Define "not working".

Answer (score 1):

There are many options. The documentation for [Encode](https://metacpan.org/module/Encode) and [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) will help you find one.

I think I'd do it something like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(cp1252)';
binmode STDIN,  ':encoding(UTF-8)';

print while <>;
```

Comment: Hi Dave, Script is getting completed successfully, but file is not converting from UTF-8 to ANSI..

Comment: How do you know? What tests are you running? It works fine here. By "ANSI", I assume you mean Windows codepage 1252. If that's not the case, you'll need to change the encoding in the STDOUT line.

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for help, but still not working, we are using module here use 5.008; because of this only.. please suggest.

Comment: You mean 5.8. There is no 5.008. That was a rather important piece of information to leave out. I don't know when the auto-encoding binmode stuff was added, but I'll bet it was long after 5.8. You'll have to look at using the `decode` and `encode` functions from Encode.pm. Or, better, look at upgrading to a version of Perl that isn't over ten years old.